# Gradle : Stackoverflow Error

Tags: gradle, stack-overflow

I'm using Gradle in IDEA and got below output.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually , I was creating cyclic dependency in files which resulted into this.For a better explanation see [here.](https://compsciworld.wordpress.com/2015/06/13/gradle-stackoverflow-error/)